# How to pass a delegate to another class

Tags: c#, delegates

In my main class 'A' I have declared a function and delegate to call that function, I want to pass my delegate to another class 'B' but how will class B know what type the delegate is?

class A

```
public delegate void SendInfo(string[] info);
SendInfo sendInfo = new SendInfo(SendInformation); //I have a function SendInformation

B b = new B();
b.SetDelegate(sendInfo);
```

class B

```
public delegate void SendInfo(string[] info); //I know this is wrong but how will 
SendInfo SendInformation;                     //this class know what SendInfo is?

public void SetDelegate(SendInfo sendinfo)    //What type is this parameter?
{
    sendinfo.GetType();
    SendInformation = sendinfo;
}
```

Thanks,

Eamonn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you declare the delegate 'in' class A, you declare it as a sub-type of class A.  So it's of type `ClassA.SendInfo` for example.  In class B you could use

```
public void SetDelegate(ClassA.SendInfo sendinfo)
```

Alternatively, declare the delegate outside of the code for class A - then it will simply be another type you can reference by name (`SendInfo`).

Answer (score 11):

Why are you declaring two separate delegate types with the same signature? Declare a *single* delegate type (if you really have to - use the `Func` and `Action` families where possible) outside any other classes, and use that everywhere.

You need to be aware that when you write:

```
public delegate void SendInfo(string[] info);
```

that really is declaring a *type* - and you can declare that type directly in a namespace; it doesn't have to be the member of another type.

Comment: Like Jon mentions, Action<string[]> would be a good type to use for the delegate instead of defining a new one.

Answer (score 7):

Just declare the delegate *once* directly inside your namespace and **not** inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `using static`.

class A contains delegate declaration.

```
public delegate void SendInfo(string[] info);
```

class B contains delegate type usage.

```
using static ClassA.SendInfo;

public void SetDelegate(SendInfo sendinfo)
{
    ...
}
```